# New/different page for different organization IDs in Jaspersoft report

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm looking for any suggestions on how to print a new/different page for different organization IDs. I created a jaspersoft grouping and was thinking of adding a print when expression to the organization ID group header. Would that be the way to go? Can anyone help me with the expression that I would need for that?

Answer (score 1):

"Start New Page" (`isStartNewPage="true"`) in the Appearance tab of the Properties for the Group Header is all that is necessary to start on a new page for every new group. Group Expression for your situation would simply be something like `$F{organizationID}`.

Here's an example that groups on $F{city}, lists $F{CustomerID} and starts a new page for every new $F{city}:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.20.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="62ac07f5-f11e-4179-aedb-a42e850c1ea8">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="northwind"/>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[Northwind.Customers]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="City" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="City"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[City]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CustomerID" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="CustomerID"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[CustomerID]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <group name="City" isStartNewPage="true">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{City}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="12" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="12" uuid="bdf3f7ab-bf1d-451e-a2ad-831a551ce388"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Company Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="12" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="12" uuid="c7bcc5aa-8051-48ad-a0d6-fe27c68da204"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CustomerID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```